# sed Back-references used to replace

Tags: regex, sed, backreference

there is a string `a_b_c_d`. I want to replace `_` with `-` in the string between `a_` and `_d`. Below is processing.

```
echo "a_b_c_d" | sed -E 's/(.+)_(.+)_(.+)/\1`s/_/-/g \2`\3/g'
```

But it does not work. how can I reuse the `\2` to replace its content?

Comment: `x_a_b_c_y` -> `x_a-b-c_y`?

Comment: sure.All I want is find the specify location and replace its partial content one time.

Answer (score 1):

Perl allows to use code in replacement section with `e` modifier

```
$ echo 'a_b_c_d' | perl -pe 's/a_\K.*(?=_d)/$&=~tr|_|-|r/e'
a_b-c_d
$ echo 'x_a_b_c_y' | perl -pe 's/x_\K.*(?=_y)/$&=~tr|_|-|r/e'
x_a-b-c_y
```

- `$&=~tr|_|-|r` here `$&` is the matched portion, and `tr` is applied on that to replace `_` to `-`
- `a_\K` this will match `a_` but won't be part of matched portion
- `(?=_d)` positive lookahead to match `_d` but won't be part of matched portion

With `sed` (tested on `GNU sed 4.2.2`, not sure of syntax for other versions)

```
$ echo 'a_b_c_d' | sed -E ':a s/(a_.*)_(.*_d)/\1-\2/; ta'
a_b-c_d
$ echo 'x_a_b_c_y' | sed -E ':a s/(x_.*)_(.*_y)/\1-\2/; ta'
x_a-b-c_y
```

- `:a` label `a`
- `s/(a_.*)_(.*_d)/\1-\2/` substitute one `_` with `-` between `a_` and `_d`
- `ta` go to label `a` as long as the substitution succeeds

Comment: pretty!Can I use same in sed replace?I am not familar with perl.

Comment: @focuszheng no you can't

Comment: It seems like perl string function is power than sed and other.

Comment: @Sundeep,you are skilled.

Comment: @sudeep,It is understood well using tag in sed.

Comment: I suggest you make the last `sed` general: `sed -E ':a s/^([^_]*_.*)_(.*_[^_]*$)/\1-\2/; ta'`. BTW 1+

Comment: I do not understand s/^([^_]*_.*)_(.*_[^_]*$)/\1-\2/ how does sed work?

Answer (score 1):

gnu sed:

```
$ sed -r 's/_/-/g;s/(^[^-]+)-/\1_/;s/-([^-]+$)/_\1/' <<<'x_a_b_c_y'
x_a-b-c_y
```

The idea is, replacing all `_` by `-`, then restoring the ones you want to keep.

### update

if the fields separated by `_` contains `-`, we can make use `ge` of gnu sed:

```
 sed -r 's/(^[^_]+_)(.*)(_[^_]+$)/echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed "s|_|-|g")"\3"/ge'
```

For example we want `----_f-o-o_b-a-r_----` to be `----_f-o-o-b-a-r_----`:

```
 sed -r 's/(^[^_]+_)(.*)(_[^_]+$)/echo "\1"$(echo "\2"\|sed "s|_|-|g")"\3"/ge' <<<'----_f-o-o_b-a-r_----'
----_f-o-o-b-a-r_----
```

Comment: It is not precise.you must replace the right positonal string.

Comment: That's good but what if `a` and `b`s are simple placeholders for other substrings that might contain `-` as well?

Comment: @focuszheng I don't get it, can you make an example what is right positional string?

Comment: @revo for example?

Comment: `a.-.a_b.-.b_c.-.c`

Comment: @kent,I mean I can not understand your syntax at all.

Comment: @revo then the cmd above will fail. if we stick to gnu sed, we need `s/../../ge`

Comment: @focuszheng there are 3 `s/../../` s.

Comment: @revo added the `ge` alternative

Comment: @kent understood your first expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Following Kent's suggestion, and if you do not need a general solution, this works:

```
$ echo 'a_b_c+d_x' | tr '_' '-' | sed -E 's/^([a-z]+)-(.+)-([a-z]+)$/\1_\2_\3/g'
$ a_b-c+d_x
```

The character classes should be adjusted to match the leading and trailing parts of your input string. Fails, of course, if a or x contain the '-' character.